# SQL Server stored procedure - how to sort the records with tree format?

Tags: sql-server, sorting, stored-procedures

I have a table with these records:

```
+----+-------------+---------+
| ID | Name        | ParentID|
+----+-------------+---------+
|  1 | Item 1      |   -1    |
|  2 | Item 2      |   -1    |
|  3 | Item 1.1    |    1    |
|  4 | Item 1.2    |    1    |
|  5 | Item 2.1    |    2    |
|  6 | Item 1.1.1  |    3    |
|  7 | Item 1.2.1  |    4    |
|  8 | Item 2.2    |    2    |
|  9 | Item 1.1.1.1|    6    |
+----+-------------+---------+
```

I want select the records with tree format.

How to get result like below table with a stored procedure? The values of `Name` column are temporary, it could be ANY WORD.

```
+----+-------------+---------+
| ID | Name        | ParentID|
+----+-------------+---------+
|  1 | Item 1      |   -1    |
|  3 | Item 1.1    |    1    |
|  6 | Item 1.1.1  |    3    |
|  9 | Item 1.1.1.1|    6    |
|  4 | Item 1.2    |    1    |
|  7 | Item 1.2.1  |    4    |
|  2 | Item 2      |   -1    |
|  5 | Item 2.1    |    2    |
|  8 | Item 2.2    |    2    |
+----+-------------+---------+
```

Sorry, I'm beginner to stored procedures. So I don't know how to get result like above table.

Thank you for reading

Comment: mysql or MS SQL-Server?

Comment: MS SQL-Server bro.

Comment: Do not add tags which has nothing to do with your question

Comment: Is `Order BY Name` not giving result as you expected?

Comment: The values of `Name` column is `ANY WORD`, so i can not use `Order by Name`

Comment: "records with tree format". What do you mean by this?

Comment: This type of things can only be done (I mean, in a situation that the depth of the tree is not limited) by some kind of recursion. I guess that the use of CTE would do the job.

Comment: So the parent of `Item 1.1.1` is  `Item 1.2`, and you want `Item 1.1.1` to list  before `Item 1.2`, while other children should appear after their parent? Not sure what you call a tree. Does the value of `ParentID` have anything to do with the desired result?

Comment: Sorry, i don't know how to set Question title for this question :( . But you can see the values of second table is result of first table after execute store procedure ( I need a store procedure to get result like second table from first table)

Comment: Parent of `Item 1.1.x` is `Item 1.1`. I don't know what it is called!

Comment: yes! the value of ParentID have to do with the desired result @trincot

Comment: So you have defined the relationship in two ways: via the `Name`, and via the `ParentID-ID` match. But the two are in contradiction, they point to different parent-relationships. I gave the example above.

Comment: @trincot i was update my answer. The second table have Relationship `ParentID-ID`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think parent nodes must be before its child nodes.
Here is my query

```
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE( ID int,  Name   varchar(20)  , ParentID int)

INSERT INTO @SampleData VALUES (  1 ,' Item 1',   -1    )
INSERT INTO @SampleData VALUES ( 2 ,' Item 2'      ,   -1    )
INSERT INTO @SampleData VALUES (  3 ,' Item 1.1'    ,    1    )
INSERT INTO @SampleData VALUES (  4 ,' Item 1.2'    ,    1    )
INSERT INTO @SampleData VALUES (  5 ,' Item 2.1'    ,   2    )
INSERT INTO @SampleData VALUES (  6 ,' Item 1.1.1'  ,   4    )
INSERT INTO @SampleData VALUES (  7 ,' Item 1.2.1'  ,    6    )
INSERT INTO @SampleData VALUES (  8 ,' Item 2.2'    ,    2    )

;with cte as (
    select t.Id, t.Name, t.ParentID, 1 as lev, t.Id AS RootId
    from @SampleDAta t
    where t.ParentID = -1
    union all
    select t.ID, t.Name,t.ParentID,cte.lev +1, cte.RootId 
    from cte 
    INNER JOIN @SampleDAta t on t.ParentID = cte.Id
    )
SELECT c.Id, c.Name, c.ParentID FROM cte c
ORDER BY c.RootId, c.lev  
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Result:

[image]

If you want to sort like a depth-search-tree, I can do it by a function

```
CREATE TABLE SampleData ( ID int,  Name   varchar(20)  , ParentID int)

INSERT INTO SampleData VALUES (  1 ,' Item 1',   -1    )
INSERT INTO SampleData VALUES ( 2 ,' Item 2'      ,   -1    )
INSERT INTO SampleData VALUES (  3 ,' Item 1.1'    ,    1    )
INSERT INTO SampleData VALUES (  4 ,' Item 1.2'    ,    1    )
INSERT INTO SampleData VALUES (  5 ,' Item 2.1'    ,   2    )
INSERT INTO SampleData VALUES (  6 ,' Item 1.1.1'  ,   3    )
INSERT INTO SampleData VALUES (  7 ,' Item 1.2.1'  ,    4    )
INSERT INTO SampleData VALUES (  8 ,' Item 2.2'    ,    2    )
```

Now Create function

```
CREATE FUNCTION DisplayTree
(
    @RootId int
)
RETURNS 
@result TABLE (
    ID int,  Name   varchar(20)  , ParentID int
    )
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Temp AS TABLE 
    (
        ID int,  Name   varchar(20)  , ParentID int
    )
    INSERT INTO @Temp SELECT * FROM SampleData WHERE ParentID = @RootId

    WHILE(EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @Temp t))
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @CurrentRootId int
        SELECT TOP 1 @CurrentRootId = t.ID FROM @Temp t ORDER BY t.ID ASC
        INSERT INTO @result SELECT * FROM @Temp t WHERE t.ID = @CurrentRootId
        DELETE FROM @Temp WHERE ID = @CurrentRootId

        INSERT INTO @result SELECT * FROM dbo.DisplayTree(@CurrentRootId)
    END

    RETURN ;
END
GO
```

AND Execute function

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.DisplayTree(-1)
```

Comment: The values of table is dynamic! It will be inserted, edited or deleted at anytime!

Comment: More,parent  of `Item 1.1.1` is `1.1`. And unlimit level (1.1.1.1 or more)

Comment: I just used a recursive function to caculate from Id and ParentId. Name is not important. And from your data, parent of Item 1.1.1 is item with Id '4', it is item 1.2

Comment: You could add more data and try with my query

Comment: That Nearlike what i need! But parent of Item `1.1.1` is `1.1`, or `1.1.1.1` is child of `1.1.1`,  `1.1.1.1.1` is child `1.1.1.1` ,..... is is unlimit level :(

Comment: Oh, so sorry , my value is wrong. Will store support for unlimit level?

Comment: Why? `Item 1.1.1` is only a name. Its parentId is `4` - that has Id = `4` and name = `Item 1.2`.

Comment: It support for unlimit level. You could add more data and try it.

Comment: It work for me!  Many thank, this is store procedure what i need! You are a genius!!!! Thank you so much.

Comment: Oh, it work don't like what i need in level 3 or higher. http://imgur.com/a/mTkjH

Comment: I want all childs behind there parent

Comment: I was seen your additional. That Function is working for me, it realy what i need .Sorry for bothering you very much! I will never forget! Wishing you success with your work! My English is bad but you understand what i need! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the columns to N number of columns and then need to use Order By those columns.

**Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE #TAB(ID INT, Name VARCHAR(20),ParentID INT)

INSERT INTO #TAB 
SELECT 1, 'Item 1', -1 
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Item 2' , -1 
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Item 1.1' , 1 
UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Item 1.2' , 1 
UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'Item 2.1' , 2 
UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'Item 1.1.1', 4 
UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'Item 1.2.1', 6 
UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 'Item 2.2', 2
```

I converted `Name` column to `XML` and then I made columns from Tags using XML method `value`

```
;WITH CTE AS
( 
    SELECT
        ID, 
        Name,
        ParentID,
        CAST('<M>'+REPLACE (REPLACE(Name,' ','.'),'.','</M><M>')+'</M>' AS XML)
        AS XML_SPLT
    FROM  #TAB 
)
SELECT
     ID, 
     Name,
     ParentID,
     XML_SPLT.value('/M[1]', 'varchar(50)') As P0,
     XML_SPLT.value('/M[2]', 'int') As P1,
     XML_SPLT.value('/M[3]', 'int') As P2,
     XML_SPLT.value('/M[4]', 'int') As P3

FROM CTE 
ORDER BY P0,P1,P2,P3 
GO
```

This will give you the order as you are expecting.

```
+----+------------+----------+------+----+------+------+
| ID |    Name    | ParentID |  P0  | P1 |  P2  |  P3  |
+----+------------+----------+------+----+------+------+
|  1 | Item 1     |       -1 | Item |  1 | NULL | NULL |
|  3 | Item 1.1   |        1 | Item |  1 | 1    | NULL |
|  6 | Item 1.1.1 |        4 | Item |  1 | 1    | 1    |
|  4 | Item 1.2   |        1 | Item |  1 | 2    | NULL |
|  7 | Item 1.2.1 |        6 | Item |  1 | 2    | 1    |
|  2 | Item 2     |       -1 | Item |  2 | NULL | NULL |
|  5 | Item 2.1   |        2 | Item |  2 | 1    | NULL |
|  8 | Item 2.2   |        2 | Item |  2 | 2    | NULL |
+----+------------+----------+------+----+------+------+
```

Comment: Oh, The values of `Name` column are temporary, it could be `ANY WORD`.

Comment: I set  values format `Item x.x.x` to make everybody easy to understand what my need of the second table! :(

Comment: No, i didn't @Shakeer Mirza